# I would like to render a camera view in a plane area (EEVEE virtual CCTV closed-circuit television)

Tags: rendering, node-editor, camera, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

*Hi everyone, this is my first topic on this forum.*

I would like to render a camera view in a plane area like a material or texture.
I think that this is a procedural texture but I don't know how this work.

I saw it working for the first time in old **Counter Strike Source** engine tech demo, but it's also used a lot in **Five Nights at Freddy's** games.

[image: Three different colored cubes in the camera view]

[image: image of camera and compositor nodes]

Comment: If you mean that you want a material to display the "view" from a different camera, this in not supported in real-time in blender. For static images, render the "view" first then save the image and use it as a texture for your "TV screen". For moving images, render the animation , save the animated clip, use "images as planes" to play it as a movie on a plane (on or in front of) the TV screen.

Comment: Hello Marty Fouts thank you very much for the reply.